What happens to the Cartesian equation of a line when the denominator is 0
Given the vector equation of a line that passes through
$A(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ with direction vector $\vec{B}[b_1,b_2,b_3]$:
$$\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3}+\lambda\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2\\b_3}$$
Where $\lambda$ is a real parameter.
By equating $\lambda$ values, we can obtain the Cartesian equation of the line:
$$\lambda=\frac{x-a_1}{b_1}=\frac{y-a_2}{b_2}=\frac{z-a_3}{b_3}$$
My question is, what happens to the Cartesian equation of the line if any element of the direction vector is $0$ as this will lead to a denominator of $0$?

If $b_1=0$ then x is a constant and there is only a relationship between y and z.
